# Kendo UI Web - MultiSelect

Tags: user-interface, web, kendo-ui, multi-select

it is possible to selectively retrieve two different values​​? A name or a number? e.g. Maria Anders = text value and 1234 = number value

```
{
    "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders", // selectively 
    "PersonalNumber": "1234", // selectively 
    "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste"
}
```

Comment: Sorry folks, it's my first time with Kendo UI and I'm not so familiar with the FW ... I think I asked the question a little wrong, I think it goes to the autocomplete method. Here it should be possible with two different values ​​to search. But unfortunately so far not found anything suitable on the web, which further helps me

Answer (score 0):

so, I get the answer via Kendo UI Forum...
the solutiuon is...

```
{
    "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders", 
    "PersonalNumber": "1234",
    "CompositeField": "Maria Anders 1234"
    "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
}


    $("#customers").kendoMultiSelect({
     ...
     dataTextField: "CompositeField",
     filter: "contains",
     ...
     });
```